# Why is this code giving me a segfault before entering the do loop?

Tags: c

can anyone tell my why this code is giving me a segmentation fault 11 before entering the do loop?

```
int parsePath(char *dirs[]){
    char *pathEnvVar;
    char *thePath;

    for(int i=0; i<MAX_ARGS; i++)
        dirs[i]=NULL;

    pathEnvVar = (char *) getenv("PATH");
    thePath = (char *) malloc(strlen(pathEnvVar) +1);
    strcpy(thePath, pathEnvVar);
    printf("the path is %s \n", thePath );
    /* Loop to parse thePath.  Look for a ':' delimiter between each path name */       
    const char delim[2] = ":";
    char *token;
    int counter = 0;
    /* get the first token */
    token = strtok(thePath, delim);
   printf("got to line 80 \n");
   printf("token is %s \n", token);
   printf("token is %u \n", (int)token);
   printf("got to line 83 \n");
   /* walk through other tokens */
   do 
   {
        printf("help me");
      counter++;
      strcpy(dirs[counter], token);
      printf("Path is %s", dirs[counter]);    

   }while((token = strtok(NULL, delim)));
   return 0;    
}
```

I'm confused because it prints "got to line 83" but not "Help me" so for some reason it won't enter the do loop?

Here is the output:

```
the path is /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin 
got to line 80 
token is /usr/bin 
token is 2302687600 
got to line 83 
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: Try adding a newline to "help me".  I bet it is getting to that line, but it is just not printed out on the screen due to buffering.

Comment: Thanks ... never would have thought of that! Now I can pinpoint the segfault to the strcpy line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on the line

```
strcpy(dirs[counter], token);
```

At the beginning, you initialize all elements in `dirs` as `NULL`. Thus, here on the above line you copies `token` into `NULL`.